# Mongo C++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I am running a thread pool where a function that is being called in the threads needs the mongocxx::pool pool variable so it can call pool.acquire() to get a client. I can't seem to pass the pool variable. How can I pass the pool variable. Or can I some how make pool global through out my application?
I am following this example https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/mongocxx/pool.cpp

Answer (score 0):

The `mongocxx::pool` class isn't copyable, so you can't pass it around (though you could `std::move` it around, though that probably is not useful for your case). If you want a shared instance, you need to keep it on the heap and provide a way for different parts of the code to access that shared resource, perhaps via `shared_ptr`. Have a look at the [instance_management](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/mongocxx/instance_management.cpp) example in the sources for one example of how to manage a `pool`, via a singleton.